# user land memory is overwritten by 8 bytes kernel land memory pointer

Tags: c++, linux, memory

We finished a multiple-thread program which is complicated. I simplify it like this:

1. Start main thread and initialize a thread-pool which will used to request data from remote server.
2. The main thread new about 3000 task and add them to the thread pool.
3. Every task is initialized by memory buffer. The thread pool's thread get one of the tasks , get data form remote, copy the data to the memory buffer initialized before and inform the main thread to read the data.
4. When the main thread read data from the buffer, it will check the data's checksum value for error-detection.

The processes are run on 2500 machines and with every machine runs about 20 processes at the same time. There may be one error occur about one of the process in one day long.

First we think the cause must be the data return by the remote server, so we add data CRC check to the data response from the remote server. It proved that the data is always correct when it reaches the process by checking the CRC32.

Then we think there must be some mistake about the pointer used in user land, which can overwrite the task's memory buffer. So we add protection to every task's data buffer by mprotect. First copy the data to task buffer, then protect the memory buffer by setting it as ready-only, last check the CRC of the response and the data buffer; both of them are correct at this time. But when main thread reads data from the buffer, the data error occur!!!

We modify the code to abort when it encounters the data error, and look up the data where is overwritten. 0xffff881492499c88 is found. This value is a kernel-land virtual memory pointer in X86_64 linux. I gdb the coredump and find the task memory is in read-only mode also.

I'm so confused about the memory protection.  Why is a user-land memory buffer is in readonly mode and is modified without segmentation fault?

I don't not familiar about the kernel things.  Is there a possible way for the kernel to modify user-land memory which can ignore the memory privilege? If the kernel and user-land virtual space are mmap-ed to the same physical memory space, could the kernel modify the memory without core-dump? If so, how can I trace these issues?

In my machine environment has enable cgroup to control the processes memory on Linux kernel 2.6.32.

I have been working on this for more than 2 weeks.  Any suggestion is appreciated. If there was a bug related to this case, please let me know. There are some kernel modules plugged in to the OS which has necessary private patch, so the next work I can take is to un-plugin the suspicious module and reproduce this error. If it can't be reproduced any more, the related module may be found.

Comment: Memory corruption errors (especially like this one, occurring extremely rarely) are difficult to debug. Try running your code through a memory profiler (e.g. valgrind). Also check the code for race conditions (you can use valgrind's helgrind tool for that, but there are other tools too).

Comment: No, you can't write into the kernel space. The most likely explanation is that you are overwriting the pointer between writing the buffer and reading it, so you are actually reading from completely different part of memory than you wrote to.

Comment: The data error reproduce is very very difficult,  running on 2500 machines for a day may encounter one on a random machine.I think valgrind will not help for this situation, which will let the speed slow by 10 times. Except valgrind, We have modify the tc_malloc lib for memory management which will keep the  newly released memory not used immediately, the data error is not found for a week.

Comment: I have checked the virtual memory pointer in user land, it not changed, but the data is change which is pointed which is campared to the data got from remote server again. So I think the main thread reading from the right part of the memory.

Comment: Using ECC RAM? If not this might be hardware memory corruption. Using DMA hardware? Could be a firmware bug or a driver error. For example, an Ethernet card using DMA writing into memory that it used to use but has been taken away for another purpose, but the card has not yet updated. These hardware type errors can and do happen.

Comment: For enforcing memory protection against DMA hardware you want to enable the IOMMU if your hardware supports it.

Comment: The ECC is supported by the cpu cache and memory. I use the dmidcode and get the following info: L2 and L3 Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC; Physical Memory Array Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC.

Comment: I checked all the system log(/var/log/messages) and found the cgroup oom module(the module is re-written by our team for some special reason) has printed some error with the kernel land memory pointer. Though the pointer is not exactly the same as the one the error data, but it is suspicious. We unload the cgroup memory oom module. The data error is not occor for 4 days, then we re-load it, there is no error for 5 days.

Comment: No error from then on, god tell me what had happened!